# How to merge tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1

| S.NO | BOX |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Basket1 |
| 2 | Basket2 |
| 3 | Basket3 |

Table 2

| FRUIT BOX | FRUITS |
| --- | --- |
| Basket1 | Mango |
| Basket1 | Apple |
| Basket1 | Grapes |
| Basket1 | Banana |
| Basket2 | Banana |
| Basket2 | Apple |

Table3

| VEGETABLES BOX | VEGETABLES |
| --- | --- |
| Basket1 | Tomato |
| Basket1 | Potato |
| Basket2 | Cucumber |
| Basket2 | Potato |
| Basket3 | Tomato |

getting the output as

| S.NO | BOX | FRUITS | VEGETABLES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Basket1 | Mango | Tomato |
| 1 | Basket1 | Apple | Potato |
| 1 | Basket1 | Grapes | Tomato |
| 1 | Basket1 | Banana | Potato |

if we check under vegetables column for basket1 it is repeating the same values again it should be NULL.

Thanks in advance!

Expecting the below output table

| S.NO | BOX | FRUITS | VEGETABLES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Basket1 | Mango | Tomato |
| 1 | Basket1 | Apple | Potato |
| 1 | Basket1 | Grapes | Null |
| 1 | Basket1 | Banana | Null |

Comment: Look up JOIN in the MySQL manual or this tutorial https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: yes you can join the tables but  you need a reference to eachother, so you can create a relation

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this really a problem in [tag:mysql-workbench]?

Comment: @RiggsFolly — I've no idea how you'd achieve the desired result with a basic JOIN. The value from table 1 is repeated, but it doesn't get *all* the results from the other tables, it gets each result once, in different rows, with NULL padding when there are an unequal number of entries for a given basket among the other tables. (OTOH, I can't see why anybody would want the requested result anyway).

Comment: I tried but i'm not getting the NULL data as i expected in table

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow imran! i do curious, what made `Basket 2`'s `Banana` got `Cucumber` instead of `Potato` - is there any rule for this? at a glance, `join` indeed might be a good start. but turns out, the output is not quite what join do. i do feel this is an xy problem. we are missing important clue here.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: This is a poor design given you have to join on a string and there is no way of identifying an output order other than alpahabetically and 2 entries for the same basket with the same item going to be tricky to decide if that's an input or coding error.

Comment: The problem is that your output is a formatted output, not a relational output. The only common identifier between the three tables is the box, so your relational output will match all fruits with all vegetables.

Answer (score 1):

Using row_number window function you can derive a row number to join on for example

```
with 
cte1 as
(select S_NO,FRUIT_BOX,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S_NO ORDER BY FRUITS) RN,
    FRUITS
 FROM T1
 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.FRUIT_BOX = T1.BOX
),
cte2 as
(select S_NO,VEGETABLES_BOX,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S_NO ORDER BY VEGETABLES) RN,
  VEGETABLES
 FROM T1
 LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.VEGETABLES_BOX = T1.BOX
),
cte3 as
(SELECT s_no,RN FROM CTE1 union select s_no,rn from cte2)

select cte3.s_no,t1.box,
         cte1.fruits,
         cte2.vegetables 
from cte3
left join cte1 on cte3.s_no = cte1.s_no and cte3.rn = cte1.rn
left join cte2 on cte3.s_no = cte2.s_no and cte3.rn = cte2.rn
left join t1 on t1.s_no = cte3.s_no;
```